# pgadmin4 showing 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Tags: archlinux, pgadmin-4

I installed `pgadmin4` (v4.4) package with from official Arch Linux package repository. It worked until the most recent update. Now I am not able to add a new server. In the browser I got the error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:36699/browser/server_group/children/1 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

And from the server log, I got the error:

```
2019-04-09 21:41:49,900: ERROR  flask.app:  'psycopg2.extensions.Column' object has no attribute '_asdict'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/utils.py", line 259, in dispatch_request
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/utils.py", line 309, in children
    children.extend(module.get_nodes(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/__init__.py", line 127, in get_nodes
    in_recovery, wal_paused = recovery_state(conn, manager.version)
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/__init__.py", line 52, in recovery_state
    status, result = connection.execute_dict(recovery_check_sql)
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 1202, in execute_dict
    desc.to_dict() for desc in cur.ordered_description()
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 1202, in <listcomp>
    desc.to_dict() for desc in cur.ordered_description()
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/cursor.py", line 94, in to_dict
    ores = OrderedDict(self.orig_col._asdict())
AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.Column' object has no attribute '_asdict'
```

I wonder if whether it is only me because I didn't get anything from google search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same issue `psycopg2 2.8.1`. Downgrade to `2.7.7` makes the trick.

Comment: By the way, do you by chance know whether it's a psycopg2 problem or a pgadmin4 problem? Thanks.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen It was pgAdmin problem it was not compatible with psycopg2 2.8

Answer (score 4):

pgAdmin4 team has released the new version pgadmin4 (v4.5) which will work with latest version of psycopg2 which is `psycopg2 2.8.1`

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Bug: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4143

Comment: Thanks! Will be waiting for the arch repository to update.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, first attempt of execution of command `/usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh` showed below error that caused the web URL to show 500 error.

```
/usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh: line 87: semanage: command not found
```

I'm using AlamLinux. I installed the required package and ran `setup-web.sh` again to make the web URL working

```
yum install policycoreutils-python-utils
/usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```