# pgAdmin4 doesn't show server connections on OpenSUSE Leap 15.2

Tags: python-3.x, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, opensuse

I have installed the official package:

```
Information for package pgadmin4:
---------------------------------
Repository     : openSUSE-Leap-15.2-1
Name           : pgadmin4
Version        : 4.1-lp152.2.9
Arch           : x86_64
Vendor         : openSUSE
...
```

It starts up OK, opens a browser tab.

However, when I try to add a server connection, nothing happens. There's nothing under "Servers".

At some point, after uninstalling, restarting, and installing again, the connections were briefly displayed, but then vanished again.

In my home directory I see two hidden log files. `.pgAdmin4.startup.log` doesn't contain anything interesting, just reporting everything started up successfully. Another one has the following to say:

```
2021-02-09 19:00:22,138: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 271, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 259, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/browser/utils.py", line 259, in dispatch_request
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/browser/utils.py", line 309, in children
    children.extend(module.get_nodes(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/__init__.py", line 126, in get_nodes
    in_recovery, wal_paused = recovery_state(conn, manager.version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/__init__.py", line 51, in recovery_state
    status, result = connection.execute_dict(recovery_check_sql)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 1199, in execute_dict
    desc.to_dict() for desc in cur.ordered_description()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 1199, in <listcomp>
    desc.to_dict() for desc in cur.ordered_description()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/cursor.py", line 94, in to_dict
    ores = OrderedDict(self.orig_col._asdict())
AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.Column' object has no attribute '_asdict'
```

`psycopg2` is present in `/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages`

```
# pip show psycopg2
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.8.5
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: https://psycopg.org/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions
Location: /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

The PostgreSQL server runs in a podman container, but this is hardly relevant to the issue. Besides, I can connect using `psql`.

Had anyone encountered a similar issue and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I spotted the same issue. I found this: [pgadmin4 showing 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604918/pgadmin4-showing-500-internal-server-error) and it seems that OpenSuse updated the version of `psycopg2` but haven't updated the version of `pgadmin4` :(

In my case, the easiest workaround was just to install an older (compatible) version of `psycopg2` using an rpm package from Fedora: http://rpm.pbone.net/info_idpl_63870838_distro_redhat_el_7_com_python3-psycopg2-2.7.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

You can install it using `--oldpackage` flag, eg.:
`sudo zypper install --oldpackage python3-psycopg2-2.7.7-2.el7.x86_64.rpm`